# How to convert ARReferenceObject file into USDZ file?

Tags: safari, augmented-reality, arkit, converters, usdz

I've got an `.arobject` file using the [ARKit Scanner App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects). I want to convert this file into an `usdz` file because I want to see this object from Safari browser.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there are no official approaches that Apple engineers can propose to ARKit developers (to create 3D geometry from scanned spatial features contained in `.arobject` file). Although, you can search through Github projects, maybe you'll find something worthwhile.

Look at my own question on the same topic: [ARKit – Scanning 3D Object and generating 3D Mesh from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547086/arkit-2-0-scanning-3d-object-and-generating-3d-mesh-from-it).

Comment: @JayD, look at my answer (follow a link). It's about LiDAR's reconstructed mesh. However you can save a mesh only into `obj`, not `usdz` file format.

Comment: yeah @Andy Fedoroff just had a look at it but it seems to revolve around liDAR scanner which i guess isn't available apart from ipad? can this work for iphone true depth camera?

Comment: We are all waiting for iPhone 12 with a LiDAR scanner that can be available this late fall.