# How to convert .arobject file to .usdz file?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, usdz

I created `.arobject` file from apple's object scanning [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects).

Now I am wondering is there any way to convert this `.arobject` file to `.usdz` file?

Answer (score 4):

No, in ARKit 5.0 and earlier you can't convert `.arobject` file into `.usdz` file format (and vice versa). That's because `.arobject` file contains only the spatial feature information needed to recognize a scanned real-world object, it is not a displayable 3D reconstruction mesh of that object. In other words, `.arobject` contains a sparse point cloud, not a dense point cloud.

If you want to create a 3D model from a dense point cloud you need a special RealityKit's API for that. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793918/lidar-and-realitykit-capture-a-real-world-texture-for-a-scanned-model) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547086/arkit-2-0-scanning-3d-object-and-generating-3d-mesh-from-it) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ARGeo, but is there any way that this .arobject data can be used for creating any 3dmodel??

Comment: No, as this answer does imply. For creating a 3D model from a dense point cloud you need a third-party framework.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff is it possible to convert .usdz to .arobject? Or create it in Reality Composer app? The only thing I have found for creating .arobject is using Apple's application for scanning objects.

Comment: Thank you!
What about Reality Composer? Is it possible to use Reality Composer for detecting 3D assets in the real world?

Comment: @KeyhanKamangar, it's an interesting question, post it, please. I'll answer it.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68192037/7435893