# Is it possible to use Reality Composer for detecting 3D assets in the real world?

Tags: arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm trying to find a way to create `.arobject` for detecting 3D assets in real world. The only solution I've found is to use Apple scanning [application](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects). But I wonder maybe there is a way to use Reality Composer to achieve this? Since Reality Composer can detect Images and Anchors maybe this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use `iOS`/`iPadOS` version of Reality Composer for creating `.arobject` and then recognizing real-world object based on  data for AnchorEntity(.object). Look at these two images to find out how you can do that.

[image]

Take into consideration that you can't scan cylindrical and moving real-world objects!

[image]

Comment: Nice! Isn't there a way to just import a .usdz asset and convert it to .arobject? I'm mostly looking for a way without any scanning! :)

Comment: `.usdz` is an hierarchy of entities and `.arobject` is a container for sparse point cloud. I do not know how to make a conversion.