# Using iPad LiDAR and importing mesh into RealityKit

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, lidar

If I use `Polycam` or `Canvas` app on my iPad/iPhone with LiDAR will I be able to export a mesh into RealityKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using free [3D Scanner App](http://3dscannerapp.com) you can definitely export a scanned 3D model with textures saved in a number of popular formats including `usdz` or `obj` via AirDrop, and then open it on macOS. And, of course, that model can be loaded in RealityKit.

Comment: Or should I just use code as you have scripted in the thread?

Comment: If you mean a code written in my post? Yep. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063571/arkit-3-5-how-to-export-obj-from-new-ipad-pro-with-lidar/61104855#61104855 But using my code snippet you can save OBJ or USD, not USDZ...

Comment: I am assuming usdz to maintain the full scene when using in realitykit or other similiar software?

Comment: Your answer is: "will I be able to export a mesh into RealityKit?". Yes, with `3D Scanner App` you can export LiDAR reconstructed mesh with corresponding textures.
And you can use that model in RealityKit.

Comment: I can also use a ply file as it seems to be a bit "cleaner" when looking at the edges of the mesh versus a point cloud.?