# Capture 3D image (photogrammetry) from iOS

Tags: ios, 3d, arkit, metalkit

My requirement is to capture 3D image of any object, we can move the object to left-right, up-down or move our iOS device to capture it. After that I have to generate obj or stl file.

I know that metal and scene api allow us to render the 3D file, but I want to generate that file by capturing also.
Does anyone has this kind of experience?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547086/arkit-scanning-real-object-and-generating-3d-mesh-from-it